# where to learn frontend, backend, API etc?

Tags: api, frontend, backend

l have been searching for hours a youtube channel (or smth like that explains with videos) to teach me web development terms. l see a lot of terms day by day but they are just a mess in my brain. is there anything explain to me all bunch of them in 1 channel?

Answer (score 1):

Please check these useful resources on the matter:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eCUeoPp-5do&feature=emb_title
- https://careerfoundry.com/en/blog/web-development/whats-the-difference-between-frontend-and-backend/
- https://www.wholewhale.com/tips/developer-terms-glossary/

The frontend (or "Client-side") of a website is what you see and interact with on your browser. Also referred to as “client-side”, it includes everything the user experiences directly: from text and colors to buttons, images, and navigation menus. Client side technologies are HTML, CSS, JAVASCRIPT, jQuery and other.

The backend (or “server-side”) is the portion of the website you don’t see. It’s responsible for storing and organizing data, and ensuring everything on the client-side actually works.